# angular2 :host attr selector won't select [routerLink]

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to apply a style to an angular component if it has the `[routerLink]` attribute.

```
<component [routerLink]="'...'">
```

But for some reason, the `:host(selector)` css selector does not seem to be able to attach itself to `routerLink`.

```
:host([routerLink]):hover{
    background-color: rgba(125, 91, 190, 1);
}
```

On inspecting the html element I see that `[routerLink]` gets transmuted to `[router-link]` - does this have something to do with it? (note that I tried `[router-link]` as the selector to no avail).

I know that the selector syntax is correct because if I change the selector to a custom attribute, it works fine...

```
<component [routerLink]="'...'" this-has-a-route>
// works
:host([this-has-a-route]):hover{
    background-color: rgba(125, 91, 190, 1);
}
```

Why is this the case and is it possible to use routerLink as a selector?

Comment: It's a directive and not an attribute. This is a known issue which has been asked to be addressed though.

Comment: @NeilLunn ohhhhhhhhhhh... yes ok ! That makes sense then! And so is there a current work around people have been implementing to achieve this? Or should I just go with `[this-has-a-route]` for example?

Comment: attributes do not have brackets in html, so `<component [routerLink]` won't be matched. on top of that, the binding `[routerLink]` is removed from html when template is compiled. one solution you could use is to drop brackets and use like this `<a routerLink="/core/item">Core->Item</a>`. the downside is that everything inside the `routerLink` is evaluated as a string, not expression

Comment: I just had a quick search for the issue, but I know it was raised with reference to @angular/flex-layout, since there is a big desire to apply things based on the directives used. You can always to the `[attr.something]` much like you are implying.

Comment: @Maximus yeah, but unfortunately, I am passing dynamic routes / params to `routerLink`.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is work around for this. Where ever you use **[routerLink] directive** its gets converted to `ng-reflect-router-link` in browser you can inspect the code and see.

For Ex: `<a [routerLink]="['/demo']">demo</a>` exits in your temolate it converts like this in browser `<a ng-reflect-router-link="/demo">demo</a>`

So You can apply your css on this attribute for work around

```
      :host [ng-reflect-router-link]:hover {
        color: red !important;
      }

      :host [ng-reflect-router-link] {
        color: yellow !important;
      }
```